# Upload image to facebook using default dialog

Tags: ios, facebook, dialog

I'm trying to upload an image to facebook using the iOS SDK from Facebook.

To upload an image, I'm doing following:

-Upload image to a private server in order to get the image URL.
-Open facebook dialog with "feed" in order to upload a comment to facebook wall.

My goal is to avoid using a private server to upload the picture and get the URL, in order to upload the image to facebook directly from iPhone.

I've been googling and I found several solutions to upload images directly to facebook, but is without using the default dialog that includes the SDK.

Is any way to upload images directly from device, using the FB dialog object? Is not an option for me to make the Views to replace the dialog.

Thanks in advance.

As far this is my code to publish on facebook:

```
+(void)composeFacebookWithImageUrl:(NSString *)imageURL image:(UIImage *)image delegate:(id)delegate
{

    Facebook *_facebook;
    _facebook = [[[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kAppId andDelegate:delegate] autorelease];

    SBJSON *jsonWriter = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];

    NSDictionary* actionLinks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                           @"Always Running",@"text",@"http://itsti.me/",@"href", nil], nil];

    NSString *actionLinksStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:actionLinks];

    NSDictionary* attachment = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @"Ragdoll", @"name",
                                @"The Ragdoll maker app", @"caption",
                                @"Share with your friends", @"description",
                                @"http://www.im2.es/", @"href", nil];

    NSString *attachmentStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:attachment];

    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"Share on Facebook",  @"user_message_prompt",
                                   actionLinksStr, @"action_links",
                                   attachmentStr, @"attachment",
                                   @"touch",@"display",
                                   imageURL, @"picture",
                                   nil];

    [_facebook dialog:@"feed"
            andParams:params
          andDelegate:delegate];

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into ShareKit? I'm using it to share images in my apps and it works great.

https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit

Comment: Hi thanks 4 the answer. Yes we did, but the problem we are facing is that we have all the development done for the facebook feature. And now we can't make a rollback and re-develop everything changing the core. I need to figure out if is possible using the facebook SDK use the dialog passing the UIImage object directly or with a previous treatment. We tried several ways to pass the image directly to the dialog but without success...

Comment: If you still have the ShareKit code, take a look at their FBRequest.m file. There is a method -(NSMutableData *)generatePostBody that they use to create the POST information. They have a section that deals with images. You might be able to use that code to assist your implementation.